# Bake action does not work for my character rigged with auto-rig pro

Tags: animation, rigging, baking

I'm trying to bake the movements of my character that I have rigged with *auto-rig pro*,because the *sheep it render farm* requires it,since it does not allow to use scripts for the animations. I found how this could be done,with a function that's called *bake action* but it didn't work for me. I have attached two videos and the blender file to show you what happened...

I want to show you what settings I have chosen at the beginning..

[image: pic 1]

and what happened after having clicked on "OK" on the bake action tab :

[image: pic 2]

I have also deselected "only selected"...

You can see the videos and the blender file [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EoM0EhF6oiwSyOzEslLJdNlf_5n06_IH). thanks.

Comment: Since "auto rig pro" is a paid (advanced) rigging extension, I guess not many people are using it here, thus you'll likely receive little feedback about your file... have you tried to experiment with "bake action" using a normal rig, not one built with that addon? every tool needs practice...

Comment: this is the solution : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1c8ZyFYNnNOoCvolwf0jOXENuFymO_bTb